# How To Make Reverse Relationships One To Many In Laravel

Tags: laravel, relationship, one-to-many, many-to-one, laravel-relations

I have two models that are User and Transactions and I have made a relationship OneToMany, my hasMany Relationship is working fine, but its reverse relationship is not working here is my Transaction Migration.

```
        Schema::create('transactions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('transaction_id');
            $table->foreignId('transaction_from')
            ->constrained('users')
            ->onUpdate('cascade')
            ->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->foreignId('transaction_to')
            ->constrained('users')
            ->onUpdate('cascade')
            ->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->integer('transaction_coins');
            $table->string('transaction_note');
            $table->boolean('transaction_status');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

and Here is my User Model, I created two Relationships.

```
    public function transactions_from()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Transaction::class, 'transaction_from');
    }

    public function transactions_to()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Transaction::class, 'transaction_to');
    }
```

This is working fine I got Transactions From and Transactions To but when I created Reverse Relationship Functions I am not getting required results.

```
    public function user_from()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'transaction_from', 'id');
    }

    public function user_to()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'transaction_to', 'id');
    }
```

and in my blade file I want to show the Name of the User who Made Transaction From and To show the User Name with Transaction To.

```
<td>
                                <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                                    <img src="{{ asset('assets\images\table\pic-1.jpg') }}" class="rounded-circle me-2 width36 height36" alt="">
                                    <span>{{ $transaction->transaction_from->user_from->name }}</span>
                                </div>
                            </td>
```

Please suggest me where I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

you have made relation on your Transaction model with user_to and user_from on User model.

```
<td>
    <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
         <img src="{{ asset('assets\images\table\pic-1.jpg') }}" class="rounded-circle me-2 width36 height36" alt="">
           <span>{{ $transaction->transaction_from->user_from->name }}</span>
     </div>
</td>
```

and if here on  your blade $transaction is your object of Transaction model you should do like this:

```
<td>
  <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
     <img src="{{ asset('assets\images\table\pic-1.jpg') }}" class="rounded-circle me-2 width36 height36" alt="">
       <span>{{ $transaction->user_from->name }}</span>
  </div>
</td>
```